After upgrade from vuetify 2 to vuetify 3, icons are smaller and darker
After I upgraded from vuetify 2 to 3, google material desing icons are darker and smaller


I am still including google font icons from CDN link
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

And adding the icon as follows (the same code between versions)
<v-btn
 color="primary"
 v-bind="props"
 dark text fab large
>
  <v-icon icon="account_circle"></v-icon>
</v-btn>

Is there a theme to specify the

What happens when you remove "large" from the VBtn?

@MoritzRingler is the same. seems that doesn't change it

you may need to try changing your code based on latest recommendations from the documentation.  see here which shows VBtn using icon prop.  It looks like using the prop will change the actual button shape from square to circle which will affect the icon size.  to be sure, you should really be using dev tools inspector and investigating height/width, padding, margins, etc. to determine what exactly is affecting the size.

Because both dark and large props are removed in Vuetify 3. The props in Vuetify 3 have changed, and you can set icon of a button directly via icon prop:
<v-btn
 color="primary"
 v-bind="props"
 theme="dark"
 variant="text"
 size="large"
 icon="account_circle"
/>

Ref: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/
